# Consumption of an api data into ant-design table react-typescript

Tags: antd, react-typescript

[image]

```
 interface DataType {
    id: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
    ip_address: string;
    is_active: Boolean;
    Avatar: string;
}

const columns: ColumnsType<DataType> = [
    {
        title: 'First Name',
        dataIndex: 'first_name',
        key: 'first_name',
        render: (first_name, data) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <img className='customers-avatar' src={data.Avatar} alt="" />
                    {first_name}
                </div>
            )
        },
    },
    {
        title: 'Last Name',
        dataIndex: 'last_name',
        key: 'last_name',
    },
    {
        title: 'Email Address',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        key: 'email',
    },
    {
        title: 'Phone Number',
        dataIndex: 'phone',
        key: 'phone',
    },
    {
        title: 'Last Login',
        render: () => {
            return (
                <p>April 2, 2022</p>
            )
        },
    },
    {
        title: '',
        key: 'action',
        render: () => (
            <Space size="middle">
                <Link to="/shipments" className='space-action' >Shipment</Link>
                <Link to="/" className='space-action-green'>Edit</Link>
            </Space>
        ),
    },
];

const Customers: React.FC = () => {
    const [customersData, setCustomersData] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        getCustomers();
    });

    const getCustomers = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        return makeAPICall({
            path: `get_customers`,
            method: "GET",
        })
            .then((data) => {
                setCustomersData(data);
                setLoading(false);
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setLoading(false);
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
    return (
        <SiderLayout>
            <div className="site-layout-background" style={{ padding: "40px 40px", minHeight: 710 }}>
                <button type='submit'>Add Customer {" "} +</button>
                {loading ? 'loading...' : (
                <div>
                {!customersData  ? ("No data") : (<Table columns={columns} dataSource={customersData} />)}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </SiderLayout>

    )
}

export default Customers;
```

I've consumed the get_customers api, which I think I did it correctly, but the data is not displaying on the browser.

When I went to inspect element, I thought is as a result of CORS, so I turned on CORS, but it wasn't still working, it would fetch all the data in that process of loading the state, it would display a blank screen at the end.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: It's a CORs error from my console in my browser, I've turned on Moesif CORs, but this time is not showing anything.

Comment: Have u tried `[]` as useEffect's second parameter?

Comment: Thanks bro @testing_22, it worked like magic, I forgot, it skipped my head and thank you for showing me that